# Questions about people in the industry?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Are questions about VA's, producers, studios, etc. allowed on the main site?

While not about the actual subject material they are an integral part of the topic.

If there is no precedent for this, then maybe a better question would be:

Should these questions be allowed?

Comment: what sort of questions were you envisioning?

Comment: We already have [tag:studio-ghibli], [tag:kyoto-animation], [tag:gainax], [tag:hideaki-anno], [tag:hayao-miyazaki], [tag:ken-akamatsu], [tag:makoto-shinkai], [tag:mamoru-hosoda], [tag:osamu-tezuka], [tag:mamoru-oshii], plus broader tags like [tag:voice-acting] and [tag:anime-production].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking about the industry, its workings, its staff, and notable figures are all fine and on-topic.

Asking about a notable figure's personal life, hobbies, etc, is a bit off-topic. But if it has a connection to a series or anime/manga production staff. It should be fine.

For an example, if I were to ask [shirobako](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shirobako) *"Are any of the characters in the anime based off real life people?"* This is a perfectly acceptable question. [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) *"What productions did {{insert notable animation director}} work as key animator?"* is also perfectly acceptable.

If I were to ask *"What are {{insert notable voice actress}}'s three sizes?"* This would be off topic for the site. If you're really curious and want to know, you can as this in our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-), where *almost* nothing is off-topic.

Comment: "postal life" - are we talking about the mailman or did you mean "personal life"?

Comment: @senshin I'm sorry, I didn't mean to go all postal.

Answer (score 2):

I think as long as it is linked to anime - whether that be through history, a particular show, etc, it should be fine.

Questions about their personal lives etc probably aren't appropriate.

Here's one that already exists:

[Who was the first seiyuu?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14344/who-was-the-first-seiyuu)